# Display input for each property of json object

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, swashbuckle

I've plugged Swashbuckle.AspNetCore and started to use swagger UI to debug my Rest API. I'd be happy to get input  for each property of object instead of big textarea for full object.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. JSON is *object notation*, not key-value pairs. There's no logical way to provide individual inputs to build up an object that could have many different layers and sub objects, etc.